# Android Studio 2.3 error jdbc mysql connection

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Hola me he bajado e instalado Android Studio 2.3 y quiero realizar una conexión a una base de datos mysql remota.

Mi versión de java es la java version "1.7.0_121".

He pegado el archivo `mysql-connector-java-6.0.5-bin.jar` en la carpeta `/bin` del proyecto este es el codigo java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://database";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table");
            con.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

y me da el siguiente error:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code. This is caused by library dependencies that have
>   been compiled using Java 8 or above. If you are using the 'java'
>   gradle plugin in a library submodule add  targetCompatibility = '1.7'
>   sourceCompatibility = '1.7' to that submodule's build.gradle file.

He modificado como dice el error los ficheros build.gradle(project:DataBase)

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
        targetCompatibility = '1.7'
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Pero me sigue dando el mismo error, es más me da este error con tan solo añadir el fichero `mysql-connector-java-6.0.5-bin.jar` en la carpeta `/bin` del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Por qué querrías que tu aplicación en Android se conecte directamente a una base de datos MySQL?

Comment: Creo que estás enfocando mal el problema, como ha dicho @LuiggiMendoza es raro que quieras conectar tu app a MySQL remotamente. Se podría, pero pasando por un procedimiento bastante complicado, sea autorizando la IP de tu conexión, la cual si no es fija imagínate... sea pasando por otros métodos que podrían resultar oscuros e inseguros. La forma normal de obtener datos de bases de datos remotas es usando un servicio REST que pase los datos a tu app en JSON u otro formato. Aquí tienes un buen tutorial: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/10/servicio-web-restful-android-php-mysql-json/

Comment: Ok, ya se los problemas de seguridad pueden existir, solo me gustaría saber si se puede hacer o no, ya que he visto que con versiones anteriores de Android Studio, parece que si que se puede.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente utiliza **Java 8**. Pon esto en tu `build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: No funciona, me pide que active jack, lo pongo y me da muchos más errores de lambda:
Error:Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.util.function.Predicate

Comment: Android no soporta Java 8. Además, el OP indica claramente en la pregunta: *Mi versión de java es la java version "1.7.0_121"*.